# How to generate 2 tokens out of 1 token with special character in Elasticsearch (german language)

Tags: php, regex, elasticsearch

I am trying to define a pattern/rule in Elasticsearch which creates 2tokens out of 1token with a special character.

Example:

"**Servicekaufmann/-frau**"

should generate the following 2 tokens:

"**Servicekaufmann**"

"**Servicekauffrau**"

That means the pattern/rule should convert:

"***kaufmann/-frau**"

into

"***kaufmann**"

"***kauffrau**"

so that not only "**Servicekaufmann/-frau**" would be converted but also other expressions e.g.
"**Industrykaufmann/-frau**" or in general any other "***kaufmann/-frau**".

So far I have tried many different token filters and workarounds but couldn't get the expected output and having right now a hard time (blocker).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do we know where to cut the first word? Why not `Servicekaufmann` and `Servicefrau`?

Comment: The first word will be cut before **kaufmann**

Comment: Why? What are the rules?

Answer (score 0):

With ***preg_replace*** function:

```
$t = 'Industrykaufmann/-frau';  // input token
list($t1, $t2) = explode(' ', preg_replace('~^(.*)(\w{4})/-(\w+)$~', '$1$2 $1$3', $t));

var_dump($t1, $t2);
```

The output:

```
string(16) "Industrykaufmann"
string(16) "Industrykauffrau"
```